# How can I extend USB device functionality to interface via bluetooth?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, bluetooth, adapter

I have USB devices like keyboards and game controllers that I'd like to connect to my PC (connected to TV) without creating a bunch of tripwires. Ideally, there'd be something like a USB-to-Bluetooth adapter *for the devices* to convert their USB interfaces into something like a unified bluetooth signal to reach the PC. Also, latency would be an issue. Does something like this exist?

The [last similar superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/692411/connecting-usb-devices-into-computer-via-bluetooth) was posted a few years ago, mentioned lag issues, and may be outdated.

Comment: Did you try Google?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something called "wireless USB hub", something like
"IOGEAR Wireless USB Solution (GUWH104Kit)". It was a fad couple of years ago. Latency will be still an issue.

Comment: Thanks - I was stuck in the "wireless USB adapter" search mindset and kept coming up with dongles to plug into the PC.