# connecting usb devices to laptop without cables

Tags: usb, bluetooth

is there a way to connect multi usb devices to laptop without cables?

I have searched for adapters and connectors on google amazon ebay alibaba but with no luck, I am still sure there is a way

Comment: Your question is not clear  The only way to connect a USB device to a PC is to connect the USB device to a USB port connected to the PC

Comment: yes but without cables?

Comment: Please read my comment again, its not possible to connect a USB device to a host, without actually connecting the device by a USB cable.

Comment: why not, There must be a way.

Comment: No; There isn't a way.

Comment: If your router supports it, you can plug a USB device into the router and access it over local network .any printers work in the same way,  or via Wi-Fi to router or it's own Wi-Fi built in

Comment: To clarify the situation, can you explain why you need to connect multiple USB devices w/o using cables?  Is it perhaps that you have multiple devices but only one USB port?  If so, plug a USB hub into the port, then connect multiple devices to the hub.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you plan to attach.

External storage?

Get a wifi access point with USB ports.  You might be to connect a USB hub to this.

Connect to the access point via wifi and you can access an externally attached hard drive and in some cases a printer.

[image: WiFi USB]
Note the USB port, you still have to USB a cable to connect the USB device to this device!!
[image: Start Run (Windows key +R)]
[image: map a drive]

Anything else more complicated than that would take an alternate router firmware, like tomato or DD-WRT.  Then you would have to do a lot of **custom programming** to get it work.

This one has a USB 3 and 2 port.
[image]
Wireless or wired connect to existing router.

newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833164058

Wired connection to existing router.

http://www.silexamerica.com/products/connectivity-solutions/device-networking/usb-parallel-connectivity/ds-510/

http://www.silexamerica.com/products/connectivity-solutions/device-networking/usb-parallel-connectivity/ds-600/

http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-Raspberry-Pi-device-become-a-Bluetooth-Object/

You can also use a **raspberry PI 3**

Pros:

- You can customize
- Samba for file and printer sharing relatively easy plus web tutorials.
- have 4 USB ports
- low power
- cheap
- Built-in wifi and bluetooth
- Will support USB hubs (multiple if they are self powered)

Cons:

- Manual setup, load linux and samba, and etc and configure it
- USB 2.0 ports

Comment: that is briliant, but how do I do it for a printer and a hdd device, I have my wifi connected to a router (maybe usb wifi?)

Comment: The wifi router converters the external hdd to a samba(or similiar) network share.  The printer operates the same way.  On your laptop you would type into a browser or **map a drive**, and type \\192.168.1.1\storage and a  drive mapping is created.  Note:  The IP and share name I used are made up and have to be alter for your router.  Printer would similarly be \\192.168.1.1\printer  or \\192.168.1.1\hp900 or whatever.

Comment: hey, I can't find wifi access with at least 4 ports

Comment: @user7403949 consult the documentation to see if they support USB hubs.

Comment: Keep surprising me, I hope it works.

Comment: Here try this!  http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833164058

Comment: slightly newer, plug 2 into your existing wifi router, and done. http://www.silexamerica.com/products/connectivity-solutions/device-networking/usb-parallel-connectivity/ds-510/

Comment: http://www.silexamerica.com/products/connectivity-solutions/device-networking/usb-parallel-connectivity/ds-600/

Comment: about the first link, do I let my laptops wifi connect to it, then itself will connect wirelessly to my router?

Comment: You will need a cord from the device to your wifi router with USB port(s).  Then the laptop will connect to the wireless router, wirelessly, and you will be able to attach over the network.  See above pictures for map a drive.

Comment: I dont want others to see it on my network, isn't there any other solution?

Comment: by the way, is it possibe that I connect usb stick with anena to my laptop and connect to the access wifi while my built in laptop wifi connects to the main network router?

Comment: Generally the wifi access point has a firewall and/or other device controls  and/or built-in and configurable from the web GUI to limit access.  The wifi access points **would replace your existing one**, and therefore only 1 wifi connection is needed.  Q2 it is possible, but unnecessary.  Several other devices are network based and would plug directly into your existing wi-fi router as an additional option.

Answer (score 1):

There is a family of USB devices, use keyword "Wireless USB hub" for search.

In early days of wireless USB fad, there were dedicated USB plug-in dongles as transceivers, and wireless hub at a distance, all over a proprietary RF link. They were [unreliable and slow](http://gizmodo.com/314288/iogear-wireless-usb-hub-reviewed-verdict-pointless-use-of-good-technology).

Nowadays the wireless USB hubs are made with connection over standard WiFi network. [Belkin](http://www.belkin.com/pyRAMID/documents/External/p75590-a_f5u303_manual.pdf) and [ioGear](https://www.iogear.com/support/dm/download_manual/?mnid=1061) make this kind of hubs. These are universal USB hubs, so you can attach any USB device you want.

Comment: I just want to ask this, can I buy usb wifi antenna and attach it to my laptop and then connect with it to the hub? because I have my built in laptop wifi connected to the internet.

Comment: @user7403949, do you mean if you can have two Wi-Fi adapters in your laptop, and use them to connect to different access points? I have no idea, it likely depends on your OS. Simple Google search implies that the answer is YES.

Answer (score 0):

There is usb over ip solutions, commerial and opensource, even bundled with hardware. 
Generally you can use [usbip](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) with some cheap router on openwrt or something like this.

Comment: It has moved here https://github.com/realthunder/usbip on git hub, or someone cloned it.